# Python requests login authentication error

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-requests

im trying to login on [this](https://www.sistemas.pucminas.br/sgaaluno3/SilverStream/Pages/pgAln_LoginSSL.html"Login form") website using **requests** library from **python 2.7**

Post Data (Captured with TamperData firefox plugin)

```
AgEvtSrc=S55_
AgStateCode=2
menu_direto=
S33_=<user>
S35_=<PASSWORD>
S39_=10
S59_=
q=
```

Code snippet

```
URL = "https://www.sistemas.pucminas.br/sgaaluno3/SilverStream/Pages/pgAln_LoginSSL.html"
s = requets.session()
data = {
            'AgEvtSrc': 'S55_',
            'AgStateCode': '1',
            'menu_direto': '',
            'S33_': username,
            'S35_': password,
            'S39_': '10',
            'S59_': '',
            'q': ''
        }

url= s.post(URL, data).url
print url
```

This code is returning the same URL. Are there any parameters missing?

Comment: Not a requests expert, but I think you need `s.post(URL, data=data)`.

Comment: Thanks for reply, I changed this parameter but it still can not log in.

Comment: SSL certificates?